# How to view an mdf file Visual Studio 2012 creates to store ASP.Net MVC 4 project data?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I've created a new ASP.Net MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012 and figured out that it creates a file with a `.mdf` extension to store the data.

I would like to view the database schema and be able to query it manually the way I can query a SQL Server database with SQL Server Management Studio.

How to do that?

Comment: I see. But the project connection string says "AttachDBFilename" and I don't see the database on my SQL Server 2012 I've installed at the same machine.

Comment: I understand. But I am very new to ASP.Net, could you take a look at the next question please? :-] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819207/how-to-migrate-a-visual-studio-2012-asp-net-mvc-4-project-to-use-an-sql-server-i

Comment: And if I just attach the database to the server, I am afraid it would inherit some development-optimized settings which would harm the performance when I move to production. Wouldn't it?

Comment: By the way, how does it work actually? Does it run a hidden SQL Server instance to host the database? The first thing to catch my eye when Installing VS 2012 was that it has got no SQL Server Express, so I've installed a full SQL Server trial version to put my databases somewhere...

Comment: And yes, you can submit your first comment as the answer and I shall accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.mdf` **IS** SQL Server ... just attach the `.mdf` to your SQL Server instance, and you can have a look at it using SQL Server Mgmt Studio.

This whole `AttachDbFileName=` features is crap - sorry. I would never use such an approach to fiddle around with `.mdf` files. Just **attach** the `.mdf` file to your SQL Server instance, and then the database will be on the server (where it belongs) and you can see it there (and use it from there - update your connection string to connect to the server and the database on the server).