# How to migrate a Visual Studio 2012 ASP.Net MVC 4 project to use an SQL Server instance instead of a data file?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

When I create a new ASP.Net MVC 4 project with Visual Studio 2012 it puts the data in an mdf file in the project directory.

What I would like to do at this point is to migrate the database to an SQL Server instance gently, keeping all the scaffold stuff provided by the ASP.Net MVC 4 project template (I mean user accounts management etc.)

What would be the right step-by-step way to do this?

How exactly should I change the connection string?

How should I authentify my application in SQL Server in production?

Sorry for a dumb question but I haven't dealt with ASP.Net applications before, in my previous experience (which was with WinForms) all the actual users had a separate SQL Server account and it was pretty straightforward.

Comment: See [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for a **huge** collection of SQL Server connection strings - find the one you need, put it into  `web.config` instead of your current one - and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server - Express (and you've already done that anyway) or any other edition
2. install SQL Server Management Studio (Express)
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `YourDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;User ID=AppUser;Pwd=Top$ecret
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

For deployment to production, you basically have a number of options:

1. create deployment SQL scripts yourself and have them executed using `sqlcmd` or any other useful SQL script runner
2. use a SQL diff tool like [Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) or even the built-in Visual Studio diff tool to determine difference between the database version installed at your client's site, and the new version, and create a single upgrade SQL script from that diff
3. use the Visual Studio Database Projects and let VS handle the upgrade scripts and deployments. VS database projects craft a model on top of your database - you basically only ever create the `CREATE TABLE ....` script and the VS tools figure out what needs to be altered, dropped, created fresh
4. if you're using Entity Framework code-first - look into using the EF code-first **migrations** to update your database from C# code

Comment: By the way, using a full SQL Server version (not express) it works with "Data Source=." but doesn't work with "Data Source=.\\MSSQLSERVER".

Answer (score 1):

What I did is just move the mdf and log file and attach them via SQL Server management studio
The connectstring can be quite simple, something like:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```