# Database connection MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I am just getting to grasp with the MODEL controls within it. I have done a model for a user which will store there firstname lastname and email address, but i have used SQL lite to do this. see below:

```
       public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }

    public class DBConnection : DbContext
    { public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } }
}
```

As you see above I have defined the data within the User class and then created a public class for the database connection for this model. In the web.config file I have connected it correctly. Everything works perfectly my question is if I was going to use a physical already built database from SQL server would I do the same process as the code above for the model? or would it be different.

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would be the same. You'll only have to change a few things related to the connection string. Your DbContext, Models and all other code will be unchanged.

See this answer for some details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13819416/1090571